# Creating your own states in Tailwind CSS (hover:bg-sky-700, dark:bg-slate-800)

Tags: css, reactjs, state, tailwind-css

Good Day Evryone.

Im new in tailwind css. Im using tailwind with react.

I want to create my oun states words, like `hover:...` or `dark:...`. This, in my opinion, would be very convenient. But I don't know, is there such possibility (in react and tailwind)?

I hope the answer to this question will be useful to many. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Custom Variants in React Components:

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const buttonClasses = classNames(
    'bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 active:bg-blue-900',
    'text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded'
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <button className={buttonClasses}>My Button</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```